# UML class attribute cardinality: at least one of these but not none

Tags: database-design, xsd, uml

I have a class which stores some required data from the EXIF of a photography. There are options in the requierement:

I need `FocalLengthIn35mmFilm`
or (`FocalLength` and `FocalPlaneXResolution` and `FocalPlaneYResolution`).

It would correspond to SQL statements:

```
create table Photo(
  /* Whatever */
  FocalLengthIn35mmFilm FLOAT null,
  FocalLength FLOAT null,
  FocalPlaneXResolution FLOAT null,
  FocalPlaneYResolution FLOAT null,
  constraint AtLeastOneFocal CHECK (
    FocalLengthIn35mmFilm is not null OR (
        FocalLength is not null AND
        FocalPlaneXResolution is not null AND
        FocalPlaneYResolution is not null
        )
  )
)
```

The xsd schema would be something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100228/xml-schema-construct-for-any-one-or-more-of-these-elements-but-must-be-at-least)

I would define/draw the corresponding UML schema but I have no idea about how to model this "option in cardinality". Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply would include a constraint like this:

[image]

Notes:

- You would rather use `!= Null` or the like to make it a bool expression. I simply copied your SQL-like syntax.
- I have not included all attributes.
- The constraint could also be written in OCL which makes it more formal (for those who insist on that). However, my OCL is still not that fluent that I could write it well formed.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Thomas Kilian,
OCL is a clean way to formalize these contraints for UML, it would be:

```
context Photo inv : 
(
self.FocalLengthIn35mmFilm->notEmpty() 
  or (
  self.FocalLenght->notEmpty() and
  self.FocalPlaneXResolution->notEmpty() and
  self.FocalPlaneYResolution->notEmpty()
  )
)
```